# vi editor in ubuntu cursor on top of character wont delete

Tags: ubuntu, editor

I'm running ubuntu and the cursor in vi won't delete character before cursor.
The cursor "white box" will jump on top of previous character when I use the x command. then if I press x command again it will delete the second character while placing the previous character in its place. example:

ABC[]   *[]represents cursor"white box"

I want to delete c vi does this when press command x once:
AB[C] 
then command x again vi does this:
A[C]

my question is this:
How do I get a blank cursor "white box" because when I use the command L the cursor won't get of the character and move on its own to the right.

Thank you for any help you guys can give me.

Comment: Actually the problem was that when I escaped to command mode the cursor jumped on top of the character. When I went back into insert mode the cursor was still on top of that same character and would start inserting text before the cursor and would insert new text before the old characters. The solution was that on escape mode to press a so the cursor would be infront of the character by itself and insert new text in the blank area.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I got what you mean, but I suspect you have CAPS LOCK on, so that `x` (delete character under cursor) becomes `X` (delete character preceding the cursor), which would explain why `ABC` becomes `AC` rather than `AB`.

Comment: Hi UncleZeiv, Thank you for your response.